# Can't get impress.js working

Tags: javascript, impress.js

I tried to start with [impress.js](https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/) to create some HTML/CSS3 presentations.
Unfortunately I cannot get even the simplest example working.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Impress Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="impress">
        <div id="start">
            <p style='width:1000px;font-size:80px;text-align:center'>Creating Stunning Visualizations</p>
            <p>Impress.js</p>
        </div>

        <div id="slide2" data-x="-1200" data-y="0">
            <p style='width:1000px;font-size:80px;'>First Slide Moves From Left To Right</p>
            <p>Impress.js</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/impress.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">impress().init();</script>
</body>
```

Howver, in Firefox (tested also in Chrome) I get the following error in dev console:

```
Empty string passed to getElementById() @ impress.js:90
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every div that you want to be a step in `div#impress` should have a `class="step"` added to it.

This code should work

```
<div id="impress">
    <div class="step" id="start">
        <p style='width:1000px;font-size:80px;text-align:center'>Creating Stunning Visualizations</p>
        <p>Impress.js</p>
    </div>

    <div class="step" id="slide2" data-x="-1200" data-y="0">
        <p style='width:1000px;font-size:80px;'>First Slide Moves From Left To Right</p>
        <p>Impress.js</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's worth adding that you can use [impress-console](https://github.com/regebro/impress-console) to create notes for your presentation.  To create the notes for a given slide, the notes should be put in a div with `class="notes"`, which resides inside the div with `class="step"`.  To open the notes console, just press the P key.